# How to get table row by input value?

Tags: jquery

I have hidden input in table rows with some value.

How can i get table row by input value?

```
var row = $('#table tbody tr td input contains("' + arr[i] + '")').closest('tr')
```

doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
var row = $('#table tbody tr td input[value="'+arr[i]+'"').closest('tr');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var inputval=2;
    var row = jQuery('#table tr td input[value="' + inputval + '"]').closest('tr');
    alert(row.attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
      <tr id="tr-1">
        <td><input type="hidden" value="1" name="hidden-val">   </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id='tr-2'>
        <td><input type="hidden" value="2" name="hidden-val"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Note: Replace `inputval` with your `arr[i]`